# C# Console App .exe Not Running Outside of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, console-application, exe

I'm trying to run my .exe file for a console app I made. When I go to /bin/debug/~~~.exe it won't run. However, it still manages to build from inside Visual Studio.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Do you get an error in system events on computer or any kind of error?

Comment: Are you sure it's not running then exiting right away? Try opening a console window first, then cd to the directory the exe is in. Then run the program from the c-prompt.

Comment: I got no error at all, it won't even open, it just won't load. The "loading cursor" stays on the screen when I try and I've left it there for about an hour before checking here.

Comment: Post the code. How do you expect us to be able to help without it?

Comment: It's not a problem with the code, I've encountered the same error with different programs. It's most likely a problem with Visual Studios, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same situation, my exe is just a simple Hello World console. After a lot of trials and errors, I figured out it is just my antivirus (Avast Free Antivirus) pausing it. Whitelisting my exe solves the problem. Hope it is your case too.

Answer (score 0):

Its my antivirus which is blocking my application. After uninstalling everything is working properly.